# How can I align the table?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{./}{Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Simulation result.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Plot the sequences of the channel for nine cases (different number of reflectors).
            \begin{table}[h!]
            \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=8.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=16.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=32.eps}\\
            M=8 & M= 16& M=32\\
            \hline
            \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=64.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=128.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=256.eps}\\
            M=64 & M=128 & M=256\\
            \hline
            \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=512.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=1024.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=2056.eps}\\
            M=512 & M=1024 & M=2056\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \end{center}
            \end{table}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

However, I want to align like the following:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a full MWE that demonstrates the problem, not just code snippets.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `table` environment, since you seem to want the table inline, and it has no `\caption`.  Get rid of `center`, since you want it right-aligned.

Instead, within its own paragraph, I add an `\hfill` to push the `tabular` array of images to the right.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{./}{Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Simulation result.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Plot the sequences of the channel for nine cases (different number of reflectors).
%           \begin{table}[h!]
%            \begin{center}

\hfill
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=8.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=16.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=32.eps}\\
            M=8 & M= 16& M=32\\
            \hline
            \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=64.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=128.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=256.eps}\\
            M=64 & M=128 & M=256\\
            \hline
            \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=512.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=1024.eps}
            & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{channel_M=2056.eps}\\
            M=512 & M=1024 & M=2056\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
%            \end{center}
%            \end{table}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]